# "The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format" with SmtpClient

Tags: c#, .net

I use SmtpClient to send email as below code:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("host", 587);
client.EnableSsl = true;

client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "pass");

MailAddress from = new MailAddress("from_mail", String.Empty, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

MailAddress to = new MailAddress("to_mail");
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
message.Body = "Say hello";
message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
message.Subject = "Testing";
message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

client.Send(message);
```

If I use .Net Framework 4.5, it will raise the error:The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.
If I use .Net Framework 4.6.1, it will send mail successfully.

Please give me recommandation?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Could be a TLS version issue.

What happens if you set System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol to use tls1.2 before initializing the SMTP client?

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: Thanks KristoferA! It works for me. The Mail Server is on the customer side. Maybe it uses TLS 1.2?

Comment: The default setting here was `SecurityProtocolType.Tls` and after changing it to the suggested value, the issue has automagically gone!

Comment: This was a real head-scratcher for me and this worked perfectly. Gotta thank you. Been a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I faced this issue when I tried to connect to a pop3 email server. I was supposed to use a non-secure way to connect to a pop3 email server and then poll for new emails but had unknowingly enabled SLL which caused this issue.

```
   Pop3Client _pop3Client = new Pop3Client();
  _pop3Client.Connect(_serverAddress, _serverPort, _isSslEnabled); // _isSslEnabled was true here
```

changing `_isSslEnabled = false;` worked for me. To make a secure connection you may have to add a line of code as mentioned by *KristoferA* in his answer.